# ISet, SortedSet, and Tuple for .Net 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

Is there a .Net 3.5 library that implements the .Net 4 classess of `System.Collections.Generic.ISet`, `System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`, and <s>`System.Tuple`</s>?

I am currently limited to .net 3.5 and will hopefully upgrade to .net 4.5 sometime in the unforeseen future.

#### Note

[Tuple answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7120845/143739).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). Regarding the `Tuple` class, it's easy to implement it yourself.