# creating new list from 2 existing lists, where there are matching values

Tags: c#, list, object

I have 2 lists containing 2 different types of object. Is it possible to compare the objects from both lists and create a new list which contains objects with matching property values?

For example if I had a list of buses (with a property 'busID') and a list of drivers (also with a property 'busID'). Could I create a new list where (buses.busesID = drivers.busID)?

I realise this question is vague and contains no example code. I'm pretty stuck here though.

Comment: homework? if so, tag it as such.

Comment: And a new list of what? Buses? Drivers? Or tuples of each?

Comment: @ChristopherEstep The `homework` tag has been deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep [The homework tag shouldn't be used anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to join these two collections on this ID, producing for example a tuple of bus and its driver. Using LINQ syntax, it would look like this:

```
var result = from bus in buses
             join driver in drivers on bus.busID equals driver.busID
             select new { Bus = bus, Driver = driver }
```

This may introduce several new features for you, like the **[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx)** itself, or **[anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)** definition.

The result is a query, which is executed lazily and produces a collection of bus+driver couples.

Comment: I'm looking to 'assign' a driver to a bus. I thought this would be a simple solution to list all the drivers which will be using a certain bus. Would this method work fine or do you know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: Take a look at other LINQ methods, they provide many ways to look at collections - you can filter them, project items, aggregate items... If you want to list drivers of a specified bus, it's an easy filter (`Where` method/clause). **[101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)** helped me a lot in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help man! How can I add the resulting tuples from this query to a list which can be displayed in a WinForms listbox?

Comment: You can either call `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or similar method on the `result` to get a good old collection object, or enumerate it with `foreach` loop and fill the listbox in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from driver in drivers
    join bus in buses on driver.busID equals bus.busID
    select new { driver, bus };

var results = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a more abstract solution, then you can use reflection.

```
    class A
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }

    class B
    {
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
    }

    static List<A> listA = new List<A>();
    static List<B> listB = new List<B>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listA.Add(new A {x = 0, y = 1});
        listA.Add(new A {x = 0, y = 2});
        listB.Add(new B {y = 2, z = 9});
        listB.Add(new B {y = 3, z = 9});

        // get all properties from classes A & B and find ones with matching names and types
        var propsA = typeof(A).GetProperties();
        var propsB = typeof(B).GetProperties();
        var matchingProps = new List<Tuple<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>>();
        foreach (var pa in propsA)
        {
            foreach (var pb in propsB)
            {
                if (pa.Name == pb.Name && pa.GetType() == pb.GetType())
                {
                    matchingProps.Add(new Tuple<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>(pa, pb));
                }
            }
        }

        // foreach matching property, get the value from each element in list A and try to find matching one from list B
        var matchingAB = new List<Tuple<A, B>>();
        foreach (var mp in matchingProps)
        {
            foreach (var a in listA)
            {
                var valA = mp.Item1.GetValue(a, null);

                foreach (var b in listB)
                {
                    var valB = mp.Item2.GetValue(b, null);

                    if (valA.Equals(valB))
                    {
                        matchingAB.Add(new Tuple<A, B>(a, b));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(matchingAB.Count); // this prints 1 in this case
    }
```

Sidenote: Tuple is a .NET 4 class, if you cannot use that, then you can easily write your own: [Equivalent of Tuple (.NET 4) for .NET Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120845/equivalent-of-tuple-net-4-for-net-framework-3-5)