# Return two strings with a function in C#

Tags: c#, string, return

I have a function where I want to return two values. Is this possible?

This is my code, but it doesn't seem to like that I want to return two values:

```
public string PlayerCards(string player1C1, string player1C2)
{
    generatedCard = randomCard.Next(1, 52);
    player1C1 = generatedCard.ToString();
    player1C1 = player1C1 + ".png";
    return player1C1, player1C2;
}
```

Comment: Will this always only return two card image names? Or do you want it to be more general, so it could return more than two? If so, you could just return a `List<string>`. I'd also consider renaming the method to `PlayerCardImageFileNames()`

Comment: This question has been asked just few days ago.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411685/return-multiple-values-from-a-class-to-method

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some options:

- Use an `out` parameter:

  ```
  public string PlayerCards(out string x)
  ```

  Return one value, and set the `out` parameter (`x` in this case) to another value; the calling code will need to specify an argument with `out` as well, and after the call has completed, the caller will be able to see the value set in the method.

  (It's not clear why you're accepting parameters at all; you don't seem to really use them.)
- Return a `ValueTuple<string, string>`, ideally using C# 7 tuples to provide element names
- Return a `Tuple<string, string>`
- Create a new type to store the two values together, assuming it's a meaningful combination. This is definitely a good choice if the values are related in a way which you'll use elsewhere. For example, instead of having a method returning one string for the suit of a card and one for the value, you'd create a `PlayingCard` type.
- Refactor your code into two method calls, each of which return a single value

It's not at all clear what your code is trying to do - the name of the method isn't clear and you don't use the parameters. When you've clarified what the method is trying to achieve - to yourself as much as to us - the answer may well become more obvious.

I'd also encourage you to use local variables where appropriate - I suspect `generatedCard` should be a local variable instead of the (presumably) instance variable it currently is.

Comment: How did you answer this thoroughly in 2 minutes?!  "Jon Skeet is so good, he's written a program to auto-answer questions on SO for him."

Comment: JonSkeet doesn't write answers..He writes programs and code in SO...The output is in numbers of upvotes...

Comment: @VijayS - I so wish I could come with a Jon Skeet Soviet Russia parody joke.  Something like "...In Jon Skeet's mind code writes itself"

Answer (score 16):

You can return tuple: `Tuple<string, string>`

```
Tuple<string, string> t = new Tuple<string, string>(player1C1,player1C2);

return t;
```

Comment: Sheesh, and I've been making a struct or something this whole time! I must be getting old...

Answer (score 4):

One of the several possible options:

Create a struct like this:

```
struct Players
{
  public string Player1;
  public string Player2;
}
```

Then use it in your function like this:

```
public Players PlayerCards()
    {   
        Players p1;
        generatedCard = randomCard.Next(1, 52);
        p1.Player1 = generatedCard.ToString();
        p1.Player2 =  p1.Player1 + ".png";            
        return p1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use string array...

Second way is to use a struct containing two string values or a class with two string member,,

Look at here:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Using struct
    /// </summary>
    struct twoStringValue
    {
        public string s1, s2;
    }

    public twoStringValue PlayerCards(string player1C1, string player1C2)
    {
        twoStringValue tsv;
        generatedCard = randomCard.Next(1, 52);
        tsv.s1 = player1C1 = generatedCard.ToString();
        tsv.s1 = player1C1 = player1C1 + ".png";
        return tsv;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Using a class
    /// </summary>
    class TwoStringValue
    {
        public string str1;
        public string str2;
    }

    public TwoStringValue PlayerCards(string player1C1, string player1C2)
    {
        TwoStringValue tsv;
        generatedCard = randomCard.Next(1, 52);
        tsv.str1 = player1C1 = generatedCard.ToString();
        tsv.str1 = player1C1 = player1C1 + ".png";
        return tsv;
    }
```

Good Luck.