# What is the equivalent of a Tuple in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

For example if I have the following,

```
Tuple<int, int>
```

What is the equivalent of the above in .NET 3.5 or the most optimal way to express the above without creating a new Class?

Comment: This question has already been answered in [Equivalent of Tuple (.NET 4) for .NET Framework 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120845/equivalent-of-tuple-net-4-for-net-framework-3-5)

Comment: Thank you, how do I close this question?

Comment: This will be closed by moderators. Next time, don't forget to check for the aswer. ;)

Comment: @rotaercz: You should see a "close" link near the comments that you can use to vote to close your own question. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: @BoltClock I think he can because he doesn't have enough reputation (close/reopen priviledge are restricted to members with 3000 reputation)