# Sort an array using 2 other arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

This is an oddly specific case, but I have 3 arrays, all with flexible sizes(but same) and valuables and I need to order one of them using the other 2.
For instance

```
int[] array1 = new int[0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0];
int[] array2 = new int[5 ,3 ,4 ,2 ,0];
int[] array3 = new int[0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4];

// Results array3 == [2,1,3,0,4]
```

I want to order the third array first by the values of the first one and using the second one in cases the first array couldn't order.
Is there a way to do it cleanly or do I have to hardcode it?

Comment: If possible I'd recommend that you create a class to contain your three related values and use one array.  Having related values in separate arrays like that is a common anti-pattern.

Comment: Make a tuple of 3 int values. Then use a custom comparer

Comment: The c# version that unity uses doen't suport tuples.

Comment: @Joska Unity supports tuples of C#6, you need to switch to the .NET 4.x Equivalent scripting runtime version.

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks

Comment: What does "I want to order the third array first by the values of the first one and using the second one in cases the first array couldn't order." mean???

Comment: This question has nothing to do with unity3d.

Answer (score 1):

As the guys said in the comments, doing it in tuples or a class would be better so

```
        var array1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
        var array2 = new int[] { 5, 3, 4, 2, 0};
        var array3 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

        var listOfTuples = array1.Select((t, i) => new Tuple<int, int, int>(t, array2[i], array3[i])).ToList();
        listOfTuples = listOfTuples.OrderBy(t => new {t.Item1, t.Item2}).ToList();
```

These would be ordered by array1 then array2.

If you want a solution without tulples please add in the comments.

Comment: Since unity uses a very old version of c#, I don't have access to tulples :/

Comment: Easy to create one though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120845/equivalent-of-tuple-net-4-for-net-framework-3-5

Comment: Surely you can just change the `.OrderBy(...)` for `.OrderBy(t => t.Item1).ThenBy(t => t.Item2)` to do it without creating an extra IComparer.

Comment: @Trevor I kinda was not aware of ThenBy. I edited my answer. Basically now it's really a one-liner, even without native c# tuples.

Answer (score 1):

To have it work with older .NET versions like 3.5,  transform the arrays using `Select()` into a list of anonymous objects (which are basically like tuples). Then use `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` to order the list according to the values from the first array and the second array:

```
var array1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
var array2 = new int[] { 5, 3, 4, 2, 0};
var array3 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

var list = array1.Select((t, i) => new { X1 = t, X2 = array2[i], X3 = array3[i] })
                 .OrderBy(t => t.X1) // first order by values from array1
                 .ThenBy(t => t.X2)  // then by values from array2
                 .Select(t => t.X3)  // we only want values from array3
                 .Reverse();         // put into right order
```

Output:

> 2 1 3 0 4